# ng disable is not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have three form with three different names and have one button and this should disabled based on the current form validation -

```
<ng-form="form0">
    //some required fields
    </ng-form>

    <ng-form="form1">
    //some required fields
    </ng-form>

    <ng-form="form2">
    //some required fields
    </ng-form>

<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="goToNextTab()" ng-disabled="{{'form'+currentIndex}}.$invalid" ng-show="currentIndex>=0&&currentIndex<3">Next</button>
```

But here initially the button is disabled and its enabled after filling the form1 but when I go to next form the button is already enabled without filling the form

```
$scope.goToNextTab=function()
    {
        $scope.currentIndex++;
    };
```

Comment: I think your logic to pass currentIndex is wrong. Your goToNextTab() function should contain the index like  goToNextTab(1), goToNextTab(2),

Comment: No I logic is correct if I print form1.$invalid is returning true and it is not working in ng disabled

Answer (score 1):

ng-disabled is a boolean variable it could only be assigned true or false and you are assign it string

Comment: The code under ng-disabled will return true or false based on the condition

Comment: i think by default value of $invalid is false in your case thats why i think it is not disabled

Comment: No I am getting form name dynamically and calling $invalid function on same

Comment: Can you create a plunker? @RavindharKonka

Comment: try to move .$invalid inside {{}}

Comment: when you go to the form 2 inspect the button and check what is the value for ng-disabled

Answer (score 1):

watch the 3 forms and set the button state like this:

```
$scope.$watch('[form0.$valid,form1.$valid,form2.$valid]', function(forms) {
        var disabled = false;
        angular.forEach(forms,function(form){
            if(!form) disabled = true;
        });

        $scope.subDisable = disabled;
    }, true);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a164xu0q/)

Comment: $scope.subDisable=[];
 
 $scope.$watch('[form0.$valid,form1.$valid,form2.$valid,form3.$valid]', function(forms) {
        var disabled = false;
        angular.forEach(forms,function(form,i){
            if(!form) disabled = true;
    $scope.subDisable[i] = disabled;
        });

       
    }, true);

It worked fine like this

Comment: can you check where is the problem in below url
http://plnkr.co/edit/eR5hT2rknflcWvuIJjLC?p=preview

Comment: create an object to store every the form, check [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/FvBC6zzEhw78LF7dev9r)

Comment: Thats great @vanojx1 +1

Comment: May I know reason behind this solution

Comment: i used this solution because {{'form'+currentIndex}} its equal to {{'form0'}} thats very different from {{form0}}. The only way to access multiple forms at the same time is to group them in a unique object and then retrieve elements like an associative array.

Comment: Thank you for more clarity on solution

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-disabled="'form'+currentIndex.$invalid"
```

No need of `{{..}}`

Comment: It is not working it taking whole expression as string